# Build Project from Package Management Console

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script that uses the Package Management Console that will, among other things, build a project from the active solution.

I'm able to get the project reference suing

```
$proj = Get-Project MyServiceProject
```

but I'm unable to find any reference to how this could be used to build that project.

Does anyone have similar experiences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look this [MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.solutionbuild.buildproject.aspx).

```
$dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.BuildProject("<config>", "ProjectName", $true)
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using this script:

```
$proj = Get-Project MyServiceProject
$dte.Solution.SolutionBuild.BuildProject("Debug", $proj.FullName, $true)
```

because the second parameter in [BuildProject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.solutionbuild.buildproject.aspx) requests the full file path of the project file.